# How to bind a value if I want it to accept both INT and NULL with PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE parent_folder_id = :id' );
$stmt->bindValue( ':id', $folder_id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
```

I have the code above. If a folder has a parent_folder_id then it means it is inside another folder. If this column is NULL then it means that it is a root folder.

From my understanding if $folder_id is NULL then it will treat it as 0 (so I get no results with the code as it is because the value in that column is NULL and not 0). If I change the third argument to PDO::PARAM_NULL I still get no results. I believe this is because it evaluates the query as "WHERE parent_folder_id = NULL" which doesn't equal the same as "WHERE parent_folder_id is NULL".

Is there a way to have PDO treat this correctly or should I create my SQL statement with an inline if to change the "=" with "is" and swap the bindValue third parameter with the correct one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using MySQL, you can use the nonstandard [NULL-safe equal operator `<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), which can compare either null or non-null values.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE parent_folder_id <=> :id' );
$stmt->bindValue( ':id', $folder_id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
```

This operator always returns true or false, not NULL, which is what you get if you try to compare anything to NULL with equals `=`.

ANSI SQL defines a predicate `IS [NOT] DISTINCT FROM` which works similarly, but it's not supported by all vendors (yet).

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick and you taught me something too, I had never used <=> before (yikes, a little to the party, eh?). It'll save me a lot of headaches in the future, that's for sure :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [NULL-safe equal operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to), `<=>`. Your query should be `SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE parent_folder_id <=> :id`

If you ever change to another database and need to update the query, some of them has an `NOT DISTINCT FROM` which does about the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see Bill's answer when I posted it

Comment: Thanks, was the right answer but you were too slow (by a few seconds hehehe)! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this ?

```
<?php 
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE parent_folder_id = :id' );
    if (is_null($folder_id)) {  
    $stmt->bindParam( ':id',null, PDO::PARAM_NULL );
    } else {
    $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $folder_id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    }
```

Not tested though

EDIT :

More something like this :

```
  <?php 
  if (is_null($folder_id)) {    
       $stmt = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE parent_folder_id IS NULL' );
  } else {
       $stmt = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT id, name FROM folders WHERE parent_folder_id = :id' );
       $stmt->bindParam( ':id', $folder_id, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    }
```

I know it's not optimal, but PDO is still buggy...

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue that I get no results because if it's NULL then I'd have to instead change the way I prepare my sql query. I know how I would do it if that was the case (with an inline-if) but I have a feeling that PDO is probably smart enough to change this for me and I just don't know how.

Comment: Do not trust PDO too much : the main maintainer left about 2 years ago, and the project has quite stalled since.