# PDO checking field against prepared :param, handling IS NULL conditions

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have the following query:

```
//query:
$query = "
    SELECT field1 FROM table 
    WHERE 
        field2 = :PARAM1
    AND ...
    AND fieldx = :PARAM1X";

//params:
$params = array();
$params [":PARAM" . $i] = NULL;

//prepare and execute:
$o = $cnx->prepare($query);
$o->execute($params);
```

How could I bind the params with `NULL` values? Will PDO change the `= :PARAM1` to `IS NULL` automatically? To make it clear, trying to compute `WHERE field = null` doesn't work in mysql and will never return anything. We must use `WHERE field IS NULL` instead.

That's what I'm dealing with now.

I must say that my first tests are positive but I don't really want to discover a side effect in 6 months in a production environment...

Comment: Can we see the code you're using to do the binding?

Comment: yes, here i posted it. I also corrected the title since I realized I don't explicitely `bind` the params but rather prepare them (apologize)

Comment: In my opinion, it was wrong to close this question as "not constructive". It is however a duplicate of this question: [How to bind a value if I want it to accept both INT and NULL with PDO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082405/). The accepted answer is to use the [NULL-safe equal operator `<=>`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to).

Answer (score 1):

As comment from `PHP Docs` says,

```
bindValue(':PARAM1', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

or

```
$myNull = null;
$stmt->bindParam(':PARAM1', $myNull, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

Comment: yes, but would it also take care of the IS NULL instead of = NULL, which does not work in a condition in a mysql sql sentence?

Comment: @Sebas well, i think you can't do that. your question is somewhat similar to this and it didn't resolved [click here](http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10377549-mysql_real_escape_string-to-fix-apostrophes&goto=nextoldest), the best way to do is to create a condition in PHP that will build your `WHERE` condition. (eg, if `param1` is null then append this condition otherwise do the other condition..)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to bind params will null values then you need to use bindValues

```
bindValue(':param', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

so for your query it can be something like this.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT field1 FROM table WHERE field2 = :PARAM1 AND fieldx = :PARAM1X');
$sth->bindValue(':PARAM1', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: yes, but would it also take care of the IS NULL instead of = NULL, which does not work in a condition in a mysql sql sentence?

Comment: no i believe not. PDO placeholder was not meant for that. if you want to put some condition to your query then build the query with proper condition and then pass the value through bindParam or bindValue;

Comment: I wish, but I guess I could use some further help